# Why my tables are not create by Doctrine in symfony

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm learning how to use the php framework symfony 1.4, I'm on the model usage learning.
I've write the model in the schema.yml, and I've run the following commands :

`php symfony doctrine:build model` which create the model's `.class.php` files, but i've look on my MySQL database manager and notice that, the database has been create but it still empty. Tables were not created automatically.

So when I try to deal with my datebase, I get exceptions like :

**SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 table 'parlonsaffaires.blog_article' doesn't exists**

Can someone help me ?

thanks to any reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have other classes already cached which could cause that error. Try running `php symfony cc` to clear the cache, then try building the database again using `php symfony doctrine:build --all` (I don't think `php symfony doctrine:build model` will work in Symfony 1.4 - make sure you're following the latest version of the [Jobeet tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/03)).

Answer (score 3):

Use `php symfony doctrine:build --all` to build models, SQL and database.

(Also, use `php symfony help doctrine:build` to see more info about the `doctrine:build` task.)